# Unable to set time on Win CE device

Tags: c#, time, windows-ce

I created a software, where time is very important. Because of this every time some data is transferred I set also the time on the win ce device. I transfer trough socket DateTime.Now.Ticks and set time with

> [DllImport("coredll.dll")] private extern static uint
>   SetSystemTime(ref SYSTEMTIME lpSystemTime);

Time zone is set correctly to GMT+1 on PC, where server application is running and also on device. HomeDST is 0 on device.

My problem is, that there is always one hour difference between time in OS and time in my software. I retrieving time using

> [DllImport("coredll.dll")] private extern static void
>   GetSystemTime(ref SYSTEMTIME lpSystemTime);

So for example on the right upper corner in device I see 9:12, than in application 8:12.

Do have anybody an explanation / solution for this? It will be very helpfull, because application is unfortunatelly already used in live system and this one make a huge problems...

Answer (score 2):

SetSystemTime takes the time in UTC (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms724942(v=vs.85).aspx)

So if you're getting time from your server which is +1, you should call .ToUniversalTime() on it before passing it to SetSystemTime().

As a general rule, to make your life simpler, I'd advise keeping all your times as UTC, everywhere, except when displaying in the UI - that's the time to translate them to local time.

Comment: And GetSystemTime retrieves it also as UTC, so there I have a problem... So I just have to adjust it by timezone, and it will be OK. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I unset the answer, because the problem is still here... Even I use UTC time and set it, than retrieve back with GetSystemTime, I get one hour less. Both functions supposed to work with UTC time, but I get different time from GetSystemTime as it was set by SetSystem time. On second call of SetSystemTime it is sometimes correct again.

Comment: Have to correct it a bit. It is totally messed up from my point of view. Immediately after doing SetSystemTime I get the same UTC time back with GetSystemTime, but a few seconds later the result of GetSystemTime call is changed and it have one hour less.

Comment: And if you pull the system time control panel widget up in the UI, do you see it jump by an hour spontaneously?  Are you debugging via activesync/similar, and it could be getting its time from your PC? Could it be using NTP to get its time from the network somewhere?

Comment: Activesync is not playing role here (not any more), I saw that ActiveSync is also syncing time, so I did tests trough wifi+socket. But NTP is a good idea, I will try to turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use DST? If you do try disabling it and see if the problem persists. I had a problem where the clock could go several hours wrong after setting the system time with both SetSystemTime() and SetLocalTime().

It turned out the device manufacturer hadn't properly implemented DST in a driver because the real time clock could only handle local time. At least that was their explanation. Turning off DST fixed my problem except you have to manually adjust the clock two times a year for daylight saving time.

Comment: Could you please help me where to turn off DST programatically? I did not even found it on device on UI.

Comment: Find the registry key [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Clock] and change the AutoDST value to 0. You may need to reboot the device after flushing the registry.